# Deleted VDI file by mistake cause error in VirtualBox of VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: image, virtualbox, virtual, vdi

when I was cleaning hard drive on my macintosh I deleted by mistake also VDI file in form like this: {d903c357-e465-4c48-ab6a-3dcda13b991b}.vdi . Than when I wanted run my virtual image in VirtualBox I received error shown in figure [error figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sbP3.png). In VirtualBox I have just one virtual image named 'win_7_64bit' and the deleted VDI file was with this image somehow associated. Unfortunately because of deleted VDI file I can not run my windows on my mac again. Does anyone know how to fix this consequence of my stupidity please?

I tried look on forums and saw maybe similar problems, but solution suggestions was quite complicated and never clear to my case.

I will be very grateful for any useful help.

Comment: I don't know, but Stack Overflow maybe isn't the best place to look for assistance in this case; we mostly deal with *programming issues*. I'd suggest you to visit VirtualBox forums (https://forums.virtualbox.org/), they know *everything* about it. Hopefully, there *is* a way out of your problems. Good luck.

Comment: Alright I will redirect my question.